# CSS Navigation Bar with spacer

Tags: css

Where can I learn to make a navigation bar like this? Mainly, I can't figure out how to create that spacer in between RESOURCES and called. I'll post what I have so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FbSo.jpg

CSS

```
.bigBar {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 833px;
    a {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
        width: 15%;
        background: #933737;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <nav class="bigBar">
            <a class="about"  href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <a class="ministries" href="#">MINISTRIES</a>
            <a class="evangelsts" href="#">EVANGELSTS</a>
            <a class="resources" href="#">RESOURCES</a>
    </nav><!--end class bigBar-->
```

Comment: If you have a fixed width nav bar, then you can use `float` to push some items to the left and some to the right.

Comment: right, that makes sense, I'm going to make a fixed width bar, but how do I get the spacing between the left and right floating items to be designed differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making some of the menu items float left and the rest of them float right. In order to change the color you can just set a background-color on the bigBar element that is different to the background-color of the menu items.

```
.bigBar {
    background-color:#6E1B1B;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 833px;
}

a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 15%;
    background: #933737;
    display:inline-block;
}

.left {
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.right {
    float:right;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

here is a fiddle so that you can see it better https://jsfiddle.net/25n1dqfp/1/

It's recommended though to make id's unique and classes repeatable so it's probably a good idea to change the menu items classes to ids instead

```
<nav class="bigBar">
        <a id="about"  href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <a id="ministries" href="#">MINISTRIES</a>
        <a id="evangelsts" href="#">EVANGELSTS</a>
        <a id="resources" href="#">RESOURCES</a>
</nav><!--end class bigBar-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background of the `nav` different from your menu items and then you'll have it:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evRjKJ)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="bigBar">
  <ul class="main">
    <li> <a class="about"  href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li> <a class="ministries" href="#">MINISTRIES</a></li>
    <li> <a class="evangelsts" href="#">EVANGELSTS</a></li>
    <li> <a class="resources" href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="right">
    <li> <a class="about"  href="#">Called?</a></li>
    <li> <a class="ministries" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li> <a class="evangelsts" href="#">Give</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  background: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  border-right: 3px double #000;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
}

.main {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right
}
```